# getDocs - firebase react native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, get

I want to get a document and to update.
I tried used this code, but he dont accept the "idDoc":

```
const Doc = query(collection(database, "user_veic"),where("email", "==", auth.currentUser?.email),where("kmF", "==", ""));
        getDocs(Doc).then((querySnapshot) => {
            querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                console.log(`${doc.id} => ${doc.data()}`);
                const idDoc = doc.id
            })
        })
        .then(
            updateDoc(doc(database, "user_veic", idDoc), {
            kmF: "teste1",
            km: "teste1",
            }))
```

^^^^: FirebaseError: Invalid document reference. Document references must have an even number of segments, but user_veic has 1

I tried this:

```
const Doc = query(collection(database, "user_veic"),where("email", "==", auth.currentUser?.email),where("kmF", "==", ""));
        getDocs(Doc).then((querySnapshot) => {
            querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                console.log(`${doc.id} => ${doc.data()}`);
                const idDoc = doc(database, "user_veic", doc.id)

                updateDoc(idDoc, {
                    kmF: "teste1",
                    km: "teste1",
                })
            })
        })
```

^^^^: [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: doc is not a function. (In 'doc(database, "user_veic", doc.id)', 'doc' is an instance of lh)]

What did i do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In your first code example, you declare `const idDoc` inside of the callback parameter to `.forEach()`.  That variable does not exist outside of the callback function.  You then try to use it in the `updateDoc()` in a completely different block of code.  It is undefined at that point, thus you are getting an error that you aren't passing enough parameters.

In your second code example, which is much closer to what you want to do, based on the error message it looks like you aren't importing `doc` with the rest of the Firestore functions from `firebase/firestore`.

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVIDO @Greg thank you

```
const Doc = query(collection(database, "user_veic"),where("email", "==", auth.currentUser?.email),where("kmF", "==", ""));

getDocs(Doc).then((querySnapshot) => {
    let values = null;
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        console.log(`${doc.id} => ${doc.data()}`);
        values = doc.id;
    });

    var transactionUpdate = database.collection("user_veic").doc(values);
    transactionUpdate.update({
        kmF: kmF,
    })    
})
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).